# Change domains on Joomla site, and change links automatically?

Tags: joomla, ftp, dns, transfer

The domain in question is www.carsmart.org.uk 
It's a joomla based site that the company all ready had in place and I have built a new one but they wish to put this on a different domain. I used the AKEEBA backup, and restored it on 
www.vvvooom.co.uk. The main page is integral, however many of the links are corrupt, or rely on content apparently not there.

Is there any automated way to basically take the CARSMART.ORG.UK site and transfer it to the new domain whilst updating all the urls automatically?

I had considered just taking all the files via FTP and placing them in there but guess that wouldn't work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know a better method than akeeba's to transfer a website. Do the corrupt links belong to a specific extension ? It happened to me sometimes when some urls have been hard-coded in any file or in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to connect the new domain to the new site via the control panel from your hosting account. I'm not sure what host or control panel you are using so you will be better off contacting your host and I'm sure they will guise you or better yet do it for you.

Regards